# Food to bring to work and heat with a microwave

Tags: microwave, food-transport

As I'll be soon moving from a small town in which I can come back home for lunch everyday to a bigger city in which it would be best to bring lunch from home to work, I was wondering: **do you know some good recipes that are easy to transport and also are microwave-able or reheatable?**

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much everything.

Pasta and Rice dishes are the easiest to bring to work

Vegetable dishes can also be fun (either cooked or raw (salads)

Cooked chicken is also very easy to prepare in advance and can be eaten cold or hot; other meat.

Fish/seafood is maybe an exception, I tend to prepare and under cook a portion the night before to finish cooking the the office microwave.

If you have a fridge at the office it make things easier (and safer); and if allowed, you can keep things like condiments, sauces for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a fridge at work? I like to bring the leftovers from my last supper. I bring curry sometimes and it's pretty good. That is if you have a fridge or I think ice packs could work if you don't have a fridge at work.

Comment: I don't, but ice packs could do the trick indeed!